# unable to install magic zoom plus in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to install magic zoom plus but when i tried hit url http://example.com/magiczoomplus then automatic redirect to main domain like http://example.com/ my .htaccess file is following.

```
# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Require all denied
## For apache 2.2 and older, replace "Require all denied" with these two lines :
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/
#RewriteBase /opencart/
RewriteRule ^(image|catalog|view|javascript|jquery|admin|user)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)$ /$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable htaccess until your install is complete by temporarily renaming it `.htaccess.txt`

Comment: I didn't but no luck

Comment: What does "*no luck*" mean?  Are you saying that even with htaccess disabled it still redirects you?

Comment: that's odd - in that case you need to find the reason for the redirect and if it's not related to htaccess it's just a guessing game at this point so more or less impossible to answer here on SO